# App Inventor : background

Tags: background, app-inventor

I recently installed a background for my project on app inventor, and then after I tried running the background behind the text in the emulator. On my designer screen I have put the background image behind the text which is the normal condition?

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to understand, what you are saying... 
but try to set **Screen1.BackgroundColor** to **none**

Answer (score 0):

rephrasing your question might help

yes, you can set the screen background from the designer view by uploading an image at BackgroundImage textfield and if there are many uploaded image, choose the right one.

any component added will be displayed above the image !

with blocks you can do :

```
when screen1.Initialise 
do:
    set screen1.BackgroundImage to |your-uploaded-image|
```